# Hibernate Many to many mapping reverse

Tags: hibernate

Consider the following example https://www.tutorialandexample.com/hibernate-many-to-many-mapping/

Here many (categories) are related to many (items) and many (items) can also be related to many (categories)

I am able to see each category is related to set of items .
I am trying to do the reverse by taking the same example .
I want to add for each item set of categories . Is it possible to do it . I tried but I am not able to get it .

here is my sample code in main app

```
        Categories cate3 = new Categories();
        cate3.setCate_id(03);
        cate3.setCate_name("category 03");
        Categories cate4 = new Categories();
        cate4.setCate_id(04);
        cate4.setCate_name("category 04");
        Set set1 = new HashSet();
        set1.add(cate3);
        set1.add(cate4);
        i.setCategories(set1);
```

can some one please help me  out ?

Comment: What is your problem? what did you expect, what actually happened?

Comment: @Maurice As I am doing the reverse I expect this output 3 31 ,4 31 to be appended in cate_items table .

Answer (score 2):

This is a bidirectional relationship, i.e. objects of both categories know which object they are assigned to. You could go the shown way and manually keep the relationship synchronised. However, this is quite difficult and error prone-prone.

The easier and more understandable way is to create a method for each class to keep the synchronisation when adding a new relationship partner. Vlad Mihalcea describes this approach very clear in [his article about `@ManyToMany` relationships](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). Furthermore, you could find it in [this article about cascading and synchronisation](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/).

Here, his code adapted to your use case:

```
@Entity(name = "Category")
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    public Category() {}

    public Category(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "category_item",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    )
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();

    //Getters and setters ommitted for brevity

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
        item.getCategories().add(this);
    }

    public void removeItem(Item item) {
        items.remove(item);
        item.getCategories().remove(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Category)) return false;
        return id != null && id.equals(((Category) o).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }
}

@Entity(name = "Item")
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "items")
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();

    public Item() {}

    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //Getters and setters ommitted for brevity

    private void addCategory(Category category) {
        categories.add(category);
        category.getItems().add(this);
    }

    public void removeCategory(Category category) {
        categories.remove(category);
        category.getItems().remove(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Item)) return false;
        return id != null && id.equals(((Item) o).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 41;
    }
}
```

Btw: Auto-generate the IDs if they are not natural, also less error-prone.